# How to find the number of properties in any element of an ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, size, arraycollection

how do i find out the number of properties in any element of the ArrayCollection?
 The structure of the ArrayCollection wud be something like:

> var arrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{column1Data:"someData",column2Data:"someData"},{column1Data:"someData",column2Data:"someData",column3Data:"someData"},
>   {column1Data:"someData",column2Data:"someData",column3Data:"someData",column4Data:"someData"}]);

Here 1st element has two properties,second element has three properties and so on..How do i find that?

Comment: I question what business requirements led you to create a Collection like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data, try this:

```
public function numProperties(value:Object):int
{
    var n:int = 0;
    for each(var p:Object in value) {
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

trace(numProperties(arrColl.getItemAt(0)));
trace(numProperties(arrColl.getItemAt(1)));
trace(numProperties(arrColl.getItemAt(2)));
```

Bear in mind that sometimes properties might be missed (see [Object. setPropertyIsEnumerable()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#setPropertyIsEnumerable%28%29)) but it should be fine in your case since you're defining object literals.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - What is so weird about the collection?I am getting XML data that i store in an arraycollection.The number of inner most nodes coming in is not fixed(column1Data to column40Data)..I would just like to have a count of the number of properties in each element of the ArrayCollection.

Comment: what if not all properties are  of type String...say,var arrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{column1Data:"someData",column2Data:1},{column1Data:"someData",column2Data:2,column3Data: false}, {column1Data:"someData",column2Data:2,column3Data:false,column4Data:"someData"}]);

Comment: Ah yes an object type would be better, I've updated the answer.